# How to find and replace the quotes with escape characters in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Have a set of radio buttons with different values.

some time the values has quotes like `No i don't`.

So when i am trying to fetch the value of it, it is returning as `No i don`.

I need to know how to find if there is quotes in a string and replace it with escape characters so that when i try to fetch the value it should return me with the quotes.

HTML Code

```
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="pollchoice">
<input type="radio" value="No" name="pollchoice">
<input type="radio" value="No, i don't" name="pollchoice">
```

In the above code, when third choice is selected and tried to get the value of the selected radio button it returns as `No, i don` instead of `No, i don't`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some code ? Maybe we can help you.

Comment: Where do you fetch the value from? Are you sure the data there isn't broken?

Comment: You need to show how you're retrieving the value of the checked radio button

Comment: [works for me](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/pcsuA).  What's diferent about your code?

Comment: @zerkms.. Basically the choice comes from DB which eventually becomes the value for that radio button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will be a huge help for determining your problem. Remember for future questions.

```
//replace all single quotes
var string = string.replace(/'/g, '\'');

//replace all double quotes
var string = string.replace(/"/g, '\"');
```

If you want to output `string` to HTML, replace `\'` with `&rsquo;`

If you need to escape all possible html and quotes, you could use this jQuery plugin that provides the function `$.htmlspecialchars()`: http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.htmlspecialchars